# mobile date puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

A mobile company launched six mobile models — S,P,O, K, M and Z in the span of eight years. No two models were launched within a period of 18 months. The launch dates of the models are given below:

```
S      31st January                   
P      20th February           
O      1st April         
K      19th June        
M      20th September                 
Z      5th November
```

find the exact date on which they were launched.

Source : Me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the solution (I'm using the years 01 - 09 for simplicity):

> P 20/02/01
>  
>  M 20/09/02
>  
>  O 1/4/04
>  
>  Z 5/11/05
>  
>  K 19/06/07
>  
>  S 31/01/09
>  
>  Dates range from 20/02/01 to 31/01/09, just less than 8 years.

Here's my approach:

> I took two dates which were just outside 6 months apart, 01/04 and 05/11. Incidentally, these and [20/02, 20/09] give the same overall result.
>
>  Then I looked for a date in September (19 months before April) and a date in June (19 months after November). So my list looked like [20/09, 01/04, 05/11, 19/06].
>
>  Once I had those filled in I only had to fit in February and January. I knew that if I put January in first then the total time would be >8 yrs, so February had to go at the beginning and January had to go at the end, giving the final list [20/02, 20/09, 01/04, 05/11, 19/06, 31/01].
>
>  Once I had all six dates in, I checked that they all fit in the 8-year period and were all at least 18 months apart, and pressed solve!

Comment: Can you pls tell the approach?

Comment: Added it in an edit.